# WSO2 - Using Message Store to invoke Synchronous web service and sending response back

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Using WSO2 as Enterprise Service Bus I am able to establish proxy service for my web service (WCF). To reduce the load on my web service I am planning to use the message store in WSO2 and use a forwarding processor so I could feed my web service at a rate that it can take it.  I referred to this   [article,](http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/12/implementing-store-forward-messaging-patterns-wso2esb-part-2)  which talks about in/out service where the response is just logged in file.  Is it possible using this pattern to return the response back to the client instead of just logging it in a file?

I am not sure whether this is possible, I would appreciate if someone could provide any ideas about how I should setup my proxy service.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `replySequence` mentioned in the article by adding a `<send/>` mediator removing the `<drop/>` like this..

```
    <sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="replySequence">
       <log level="full">
          <property name="REPLY" value="MESSAGE">
       </property></log>
       <!-- Send the messages where they are destined to (i.e. the 'To' EPR of the message) -->
       <send/>
    </sequence>
```

..or you can define the endpoint to send the reply explicitly like this..

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="replySequence">
   <log level="full">
      <property name="REPLY" value="MESSAGE">
   </property></log>
   <!-- Send to an explicit address -->
   <send>
     <endpoint>
        <address uri="http://{Add your address here}/"/>
     </endpoint>
   </send>
</sequence>
```

Comment: I think your suggestion would work if I want to send it to another service, but I want the response to be sent back to the caller (who submitted the request).  Is there anyway I could do it?